# How to go from primitive idempotents in $\text{End}_A(M)$ to primitive idempotents in $A$?

Tags: gr.group-theory, rt.representation-theory, ra.rings-and-algebras, noncommutative-algebra, primitive-elements

Let $K$ be a large enough finite field, let $A$ be a finite-dimensional $K$-algebra.

Moreover, let $M$ be a finitely generated $A$-module and let $M = M_1\oplus ... \oplus M_n$ be a decomposition of $M$ into indecomposable direct summands (as $A$-modules).

Moreover, let $M$ be a submodule of the regular module $A^{\text{reg}}$.

We can think of $M$ as a matrix representation with respect to a fixed basis $\mathcal{B}$ such that the matrices have block diagonal form.

Let $\varphi_1, ... , \varphi_n \in B := \text{End}_A(M)$ such that $\{\varphi_i | i = 1, ... , n\}$ is a complete set of pairwise distinct primitive orthogonal idempotent elements of $B$.

> Is there an easy way to compute from this a corresponding set $\{e_1, ... , e_n\}$ of pairwise distinct primitive orthogonal idempotent elements  in $A$ such that $M\cdot e_j = M_j$ for every $j\in \{1, ... , n\}$ ? Here, $A$ acts from the left.

Thank you very much.

**Remark:** if it makes things easier, we can assume that $A=KG$ for a finite group $G$ such that char$(K)$ $\mid |G|$.

**EDIT (April 12) :** I mixed something up. I'm sorry. I'd like to have $M\cdot e_j=M_j$. Moreover, $M$ is a submodule of the regular module $A^{\text{reg}}$.

**Example:**

Let $p:=2, k:=GF(16), G:=A_5$ and set $A:=kG$.

Let $P_i$ be the PIMs of $A$, let $P_1$ be the projective cover of the trivial module $k$.

Let $M:=P_2\oplus P_3$.
Then, it is possible to write $P_j=Ae_j$ for some primitive orthogonal idempotents $e_i\in A$. Since $M$ can be embedded into the regular module as a submodule, we have $M\cdot e_u=M_u$ for all $u\in \{1,2\}$.

Comment: If M is a module and A is an algebra with idempotent e then eM is an eAe-module not an A module

Comment: Thank you very much for the comment. Of course, you're right. I edited the question.

Comment: I think you can't always do this. If $e_jM=M_j$ then $Ae_j/rad(A)e_j$ is the only composition factor of $M_j$.

Comment: Sorry, there are probably hypotheses missing. If $A = K[x]$ then $A$ has no nontrivial idempotents at all, but plenty of indecomposable modules. Are you assuming $A$ is finite-dimensional?

Comment: @R.vanDobbendeBruyn Yes, sorry. I edited the question. Thank you.

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg Thank you very much for the comment. You are right. I mixed something up and forgot an additional assumption. I edited the question.

Comment: If M is just a submodule of the regular representation I don't think such idempotents would have to exist.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much.